# Symfony OAuth api FOSOAuthServerBundle: crash

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, oauth-2.0, fosuserbundle

Am trying to use the FOSOAuthServerBundle but am having a crash problem, the crash message is :

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of MP\OAuthBundle\Entity\AccessToken::setUser() must be compatible with that of FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Model\TokenInterface::setUser() in /home/bitnami..../OAuthBundle/Entity/AccessToken.php on line 13
```

AccessToken.class:

```
<?php

namespace MP\OAuthBundle\Entity;

use FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\AccessToken as BaseAccessToken;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="oauth_access_tokens")
 */
class AccessToken extends BaseAccessToken
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\MP\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     */
    protected $user;
}
```

TokenInterface::setUser:

```
 /**
     * @param UserInterface $user
     */
    function setUser(UserInterface $user);
```

User.class

```
namespace MP\UserBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;


/**
 * User
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    const ROLE_ADMIN = 'ROLE_ADMIN';

    /**
     * @var integer
...
```

I still do not see where the problem can be !  My user is implementing the UserInterface at the end!

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have the following two **use-statements** in `MP\OAuthBundle\Entity\AccessToken`

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Model\ClientUserInterface;
```

You have to make sure `AccessToken` implements `FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Model\TokenInterface` which includes function declaration with the same interfaces.

now if you have ...

```
function setUser(UserInterface $user)
```

... inside `AccessToken` trying to implement `TokenInterface` but without the use statement ...

... `UserInterface` would translate to `MP\OAuthBundle\Entity\UserInterface`

... but it needs to be `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface`.

---

**conclusion**

Mismatch between argument types is why PHP complains about the mismatch between the two function declarations here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is within your `Access token` class. You probably override `setUser()` method (without pasting it here), and not adding `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface` to use statements. There is no other way since you class is first and last overriding FOS `FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Model\AccessToken`.

Delete this function definition from you class or fix use statements